# Fork connections out from a single socat connection

Tags: linux, networking, socket, socat

I have an old legacy application I’m trying to get to work with our semi-modern network. This application sends log messages as HTTP requests (one log per request) but does so over a single TCP connection. If that TCP connection dies, the logs get messed up as there is no queue for them.

I decided to use socat to try and hold a TCP session open while breaking up the HTTP requests on the other end for further processing. I have something like this:

```
socat tcp-listen:8888 tcp-connect:logserver:80
```

The problem is when the web server listening on “logserver” accepts an HTTP connection from socat, it tears down its TCP connection, which causes socat to tear down the listening socket the application server wants open.

How do I get socat to reconnect on the upstream side whenever it goes down and then just keep pushing data through from the listener?

I’ve tried using “fork” on the listening side, but that still tears down the connection. I almost want to add “fork” on the tcp-connect side but that doesn’t seem to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of socat's manpage: "When one of the streams effectively reaches EOF, the closing phase begins. Socat transfers the EOF condition to the other stream (…)". Look for "EOF" to find more helpful tips in this regard.

So, if you want socat to keep up the listening side, add `fork,reuseaddr`.

If the logserver is not answering reliably, you can make socat retry the connection with e.g. `retry,interval=.2,forever`.

```
socat tcp-listen:8888,fork,reuseaddr tcp-connect:logserver:80,retry,interval=.2,forever
```

I also like to run socat with `socat -d -d -d` to debug things while trying to get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve: is logserver unable to handle multiple-request connections (and the application still uses them contrary to HTTP standard)? Below I'll assume there's some reason to have a proxy that supports multi-request connections on the client side and forwards them as single-request connections on the server side.

In any case, doing what you want to do with a non-HTTP-aware proxy is going to be fragile at best: the intent to keep the connection open after the request is explicitly specified in HTTP headers, and so simply splitting up the requests is not really correct, even if it was easy to do without understanding HTTP. I'd suggest putting a standard http reverse proxy in its place (e.g. nginx) and configuring that correctly.